# Who coined the term "YouTuber"?

Tags: etymology

I would like to know if there is a record that the word "YouTuber" appeared first 
 time in history.

Comment: Related: [What does 'YouTuber' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277548/what-does-youtuber-mean)

Comment: WP awaits actual etymological data for the term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTuber

Comment: Mr Potato Head's neighbor.

Answer (score 3):

*[The OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/53546199?redirectedFrom=youtuber#eid)*'s first citation is from 2006:

> *N.Y. Times* 16 Apr. (Arts & Leisure section) 4/2      One of the most discussed YouTube clips lately features a young woman..watching a video of another YouTube user, who is watching another YouTuber, and so on.